# Magento 2.4.4: How to remove Reviews tab from the product page

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, tabs, web

Is there any setting in Magento admin to remove the reviews tab from product details page?

[image]

Here is the contents of catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="product-custom.js" as="product-custom.js" template="Magento_Catalog::product/js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <body>
        <!-- Create container for main product tabs -->
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <container name="custom-before-footer-container" before="before-footer-container" label="Luxury Custom - container for main tabs" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-before-footer">
                <container name="custom-before-footer-content" label="Luxury Custom - main tabs content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="content">
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <!-- Hide additional tabs -->
        <referenceBlock name="additional-tabs" display="false" />
        <!-- Hide Reviews tab -->
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- Move product tabs into new place -->
        <move element="product.info.tabs" destination="custom-before-footer-content" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a conditional statement in the phtml in my theme override.

```
   <div class="product info detailed">
        <div class="product data items <?php echo $block->getTabsLayout();?>" data-mage-init='{"Swissup_Easytabs/js/tabs": <?= $block->getInitOptions() ?>}' id="swissup-easy-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($tabs as $_index => $_tab) : ?>
                <?php
                    if (strcasecmp($_tab['title'], "Reviews") == 0) {
                        unset($tabs[$_index]);
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $_tab['alias'];
                    $label = $_tab['title'];
                    if ($label == "Product Description") {
                        $_tab['child_html'] = '<div class="std">' . $_tab['child_html'] . '</div>'
                                . '<div class="badge-description">' . $_product->getData('badge_description') . '</div>';
                    }
                    $attributes->setData([
                        'class' => $isExpanded ? 'title' : 'data switch',
                        'id' => "tab-label-{$alias}-title",
                        'data-toggle' => 'switch',
                    ]);
                    if ($_tab['is_ajax']) {
                        $attributes->setData(
                            'data-ajaxurl',
                            $block->getAjaxUrl($alias)
                        );
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="data item title <?php echo $isExpanded ? 'active' : ''?>"
                    aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title"
                    data-role="collapsible"
                    id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias ?>">
                <?php if ($isExpanded): ?>
                    <h2 <?= $attributes->serialize() ?>><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label ?></h2>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <a <?= $attributes->serialize() ?>
                        tabindex="-1"
                        href="#<?= $alias ?>">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif ?>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_tab['child_html'] ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Reviews** tab on the product page is the Product Review feature from Magento Catalog module.

Your Reviews button on the right screen is Yotpo review.

To remove the Reviews tab, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog, open the Product Reviews group, and set the Enabled field to **No**. Note that this behavior will disable the Product Review feature from Magento_Catalog module.

Comment: Can Yotpo Review button be used by the customers to leave a review?

Comment: Yes, of course! Let's give it a try.

Comment: I disabled it from Magento admin, but the reviews tab is still appearing. I cleared cache as well.

Comment: If the config was saved in the website scope, you have to change the scope to website to save the config. https://i.imgur.com/i9WONWW.png

Comment: Our store is in default config scope.

Comment: No. In Magento, you must have a website scope. In case the config in the website scope overrides the Default config, change the scope config to the website and make sure Product Reviews set Enable to No.

Comment: @CodeForGood did you give it a try?

Comment: Yes, but it is not working still.

Comment: @CodeForGood I saw you already resolve it. If any solution in this post work for you, please mark it as accepted, if not please add a new answer to share your solution. That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Comment: Sure, will add my solution as none of the solutions in the post helped resolve it.

Comment: @CodeForGood your site using a 3rd-party extension (Swissup_Easytabs) which override default Magento template, so our solutions does not work for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. We are using SwissUp theme that we have customized.

Comment: You're welcome. Once we know you use a custom theme/extension, we can help you easier.

Answer (score 1):

Go to :

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and paste the below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think view/frontend is not necessary? just this one app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml in theme overrriding.

Comment: Sorry !! It's typo. answer is updated.

Comment: if it's working then pls mark as accepted and upvote.

Comment: Hi Rohan, please check my XML file to content and confirm if it is correct. I'm still unable to remove reviews tab.

Comment: pls add the full file path

Answer (score 0):

You can simple disable the Reviews tab from the admin panel using below steps.

Go to **Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog -> Catalog -> Product Reviews -> Enabled -> No -> Save Config.**